# How to pay remaining tax? How to clear Intimation u/s 143(1) India ITR?

Tags: income-tax, india

For **FY18-19** or assessment year AY19-20, I received intimation u/s 143(1) on 12th Dec, 2019.
The mail attachment PDF had "**Net Amount Payable**" of **10 INR**.
[image]

At the bottom of PDF, it says

- I should have paid 10 INR within 30 days post 12th Dec 2019.
- Also, the 2nd
  point has *"...either online (Link)"* but it is not clickable.
- I tried a lot to make this payment, but I can't find any link for the same.

[image]

Moreover, when I go to https://portal.incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/ I do not see any "outstanding demand" - it says "No records found".
[image]

My question is how do I close this? I do not see any link where I can make the payment.
**How do I pay the remaining 10 INR amount?**
**How do I cofirm that I do not need to take any more actions?**

Please note that now its **FY20-21** ongoing

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to pay if the amount is less than Rs 100. Check out the fine print if any.

The way you pay is same as advance tax. i.e. via NSDL website. Ensure you select the payment in response to 156 and select the correct assessment year.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. Thanks. 
@Dheer so if I do not need to pay, can I just leave it as it is? Is there something that can be done to close the ITR status?